# Centering Navigation Bar - CSS

Tags: css, list, navigation, centering

I'm in the process of making my own blog, I haven't got a domain yet so it's not live(I've been building the site from a folder with different directories as the pages). I've been working on the blog and I was looking for a simple navigation menu. I found one on the internet. I'm trying to center the navigation bar and I've tried many solutions that worked for other peoples websites but it isn't working for mine. This is the code (I've tweaked it to my own colors and nav titles)

```
<ul id="list-nav">
 <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="../books/books.html">Books</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="../contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
ul.list-nav {
 list-style:none;
 width:525px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

ul#list-nav li {
 display:inline;
}

ul#list-nav li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:5px 0;
 width:150px;
 background:#383838;
 color:#eee;
 float:left;
 border-left:1px solid #fff;
 }

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background:#cccccc;
 color:#000;
 }
```

"Help me Obi Wan Kenobi your my only hope!"

Comment: Can you please clarify what isn't working with this code, and what result you're looking for?

Comment: I edited it, I'm trying to center my navigation menu, I think some code I have is canceling anything I try to do to fix it. Thanks for the notice. I didn't realize I forgot to state my problem. This link is to my entire code html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/Sederu/ZLYXr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would `wrap` the entire page inside `<div class="wrap">`. You have declared `margin` twice in the code, so I would remove the first occurrence and leave it like:

```
ul#list-nav {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 725px; //NOTE I have increased the width value.
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also, find

```
ul { 
     display: inline;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;}
```

[around line 20] and remove `display: inline;` rule. This should fix your issues. Check the live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bborisovs/ZLYXr/2/).

Comment: Is it necessary that I wrap the entire page? Also is it necessary to change the ul#list-nav width to 725px?

Comment: It is not necessary to `wrap` everything, I use this approach, because it offers better control over page elements. I've set the `width` to 725px, just as an example, because the previous `width` was not enough. Happy to hear it worked.

Comment: So would wrapping the entire page make it easier to set a background image to my page? I've also been having some trouble with that.

Comment: What sort of background issues do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Your first CSS selector is looking for a `ul` with a **class** of `list-nav`, not an *id* of `list-nav`. Change your first CSS rule to:

```
ul#list-nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 525px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And your navigation bar is magically centered. Please see this jsFiddle for a working demonstration > http://jsfiddle.net/TLaN5/. Obviously you'll need to amend the width of the parent `ul` in order to accomodate the correct width of the elements within, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I made that rule change and it didn't change anything. It's still stuck all the way to the left. Do you think some of my other code could be canceling something?

Comment: Almost certainly. Did you check the jsFiddle I posted? This is a working example.

Comment: Yeah I saw it. I realize it works if its just that code. If I give you all my html and css do you think you can find whats canceling it?

Comment: Yes, I'd have thought so. Do I want to? Not really ;) Put it in a jsFiddle, and send me over a link. I'll have a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a define size to the ul and center its content (remove the display-inline, indeed)

```
ul {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Then display the child li elements as inline blocks :

```
ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

**The inline-block property won't work in ie7, so check your browser targets first...**

Another way is to just use the good ol'

```
ul li {
float: left;
}

ul:after {
display: block;
content: "";
clear: both;
}
```

But the li won't be centered within the ul and you'll have to use javascript if you absolutely want to do this dynamically (without assigning a fixed with to each li).